# Sideways margin with parbox?

Tags: tables, spacing, boxes, rotating

How to get right margin in parboxed header? Top, bottom and left margin are ok, but there is no margin at the right (top) side of 'Parameter' header.

```
\begin{table}[ht]\footnotesize
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|}
\hline
\begin{sideways}\parbox{2cm}{Parameter etc etc ....}\end{sideways} 
\end{tabular}

\caption{Summary}
\label{tab:summary}
\end{table}
```

[image: No right margin]

There are top,bottom and left margin, but there is no margin at right side of the header, as you can see at attached image.

Comment: Somehow the problem is not comprehensible for me. Perhaps a full but minimal example that reproduces the undesired behaviour can help to understand.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`\parbox` supports optional arguments for specifying height and alignment. In your case, within a sideways environment, you could adjust the height of the parbox to get a wider header and thus a wider margin.

Further, if you wish to get space below or above the turned parbox, you could use `\hspace*` to insert some space within the sideways environment.

For example, within your code, write

```
\begin{sideways}
  \parbox[c][2cm][c]{2cm}{Parameter etc etc ....}
  \hspace*{1ex}
\end{sideways}
```

to get (with an additional `\hline`):

[image: table]

The syntax of `\parbox` is

```
\parbox[pos][height][inner-pos]{width}{text}
```

where `pos` means one of the usual alignment options t, b or c.

Comment: Ok, it works for top and bottom - but what about right margin? When you look at table you can see that there is no margin at the very top of it (looking normally -from top to bottom, not sideways)

Comment: The question seemed not so clear (what's been meant by *right*) and the code and the first column had whitespace at its top. Just insert some space after the parbox (`\hspace*`) - I'll edit my example.